# When writing a crawler, why can't I get results using xpath？

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-crawler, lxml

I need to parse the number of pages of this website element.

[image]

Code:

```
url = "https://nj.zu.ke.com/zufang/caochangmendajie/"

page=etree.HTML(Download.downloadPage(url))            #download page
nums = page.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/a[2]/text()')
print(nums)
```

I use chrome, right click to copy full XPath

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/a[2]
```

I want to know why my nums(list) is empty?
And it is possible to use xpath parsing elsewhere.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In scrapy shell

```
response.xpath("//div[@class='content__pg']/@data-totalpage").extract_first()
```

command returns '8' to me.

You can use this xpath in your code, or you can try to use scrapy

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xpath to go to the next page.

```
//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[2]/a[3]
```

Or you can create a urls list like this and then parse items through for loop.

```
urls =["https://nj.zu.ke.com/zufang/caochangmendajie/pg{}/#contentList".format(x) for x in range(1,10)]
```

### In scrapy shell

```
>>> url ='https://nj.zu.ke.com/zufang/caochangmendajie/'
>>> r = scrapy.Request(url)
>>> fetch(r)
2021-02-16 14:35:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://nj.zu.ke.com/zufang/caochangmendajie/> (referer: None)
>>> for url in response.css('div.content__article li a ::attr("href")').extract()[4:]:
...     print(url)
... 
/zufang/caochangmendajie/pg2/
/zufang/caochangmendajie/pg3/
/zufang/caochangmendajie/pg4/
/zufang/caochangmendajie/pg5/
/zufang/caochangmendajie/pg6/
/zufang/caochangmendajie/pg7/
/zufang/caochangmendajie/pg8/
>>>
```